# "Hospitality" Cereal Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

It's a generic brand. I don't have access to the box and can't find any way to check…

Comment: After searching OUKosher.org, I can say that Hospitality does not have an OU...

Comment: @Tzvi one down. Over a hundred to go…

Comment: Found an image here but cannot ID the symbol http://www.michiganonlyauctions.com/auctions/uploaded/2009-7-7/4ee8a0492Df7692D47012D9bca2D0cbc60ca4133070726.JPG

Comment: yydl, while you are right in that there are hundreds of acceptable hashgachos, you have to admit that OU definitely certifies the majority (or at least the plurality) of certified mass-produced products on the American market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the boxes have an OV on them which is the Vaad Hoeir of St. Louis

http://www.michiganonlyauctions.com/auctions/detail.asp?id=8793&bigpic=0#img

Comment: I live in St. Louis, and I'm pretty sure that the O-V is universally accepted here, for what it's worth. Here's contact info: http://www.ovkosher.org/a/contact

Comment: And if this helps anyone, the cRc has the OV on its "list of common acceptable kosher symbols": crcweb.org/agency_list.php . As always, CYLOR re whether you should accept any particular _hashgacha_.

Comment: I live in Connecticut, and my wife came home from shopping with a box of Hospitality Apple Whirls that have a V in a circle(the O-V) with "Pareve" below it. They taste just like Apple Jacks, and only a buck a box!